# How to reposition a row in a data frame that meets certain conditions?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, row, scheduling

I'm using R and the tidyverse and need to be able to systematically search a data frame for "problem rows", and then replace them with a row from above.

For example, let's say I have the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  name = c("blank", "A", "B", "blank", "C", "D", "blank", "E"),
  problem = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1)
)
```

```
df
<name>   <problem>
blank           0
    A           0
    B           0
blank           0
    C           0
    D           1
blank           0
    E           1
```

In this example both names D and E have a "problem", so I need to search for the nearest "blank" row above and reposition it where the problem row currently sits. So the solution would look like the following:

```
<name>   <problem>
blank           0
    A           0
    B           0
    C           0
    D           1
blank           0
    E           1
blank           0
```

Any help would be tremendously appreciated, as I have a much larger data frame in real life and can't make the adjustments manually. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To keep excess blanks in place:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  name = c("blank", "A", "B", "blank", "C", "D", "blank", "E"),
  problem = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1)
)

df |> 
  mutate(temp = if_else(problem == 1, name, NA_character_)) |> 
  fill(temp, .direction = "up") |> 
  mutate(temp = if_else(name == "blank" | problem == 1, temp, name)) |> 
  add_count(temp) |> 
  group_by(temp) |> 
  mutate(temp = if_else(n > 2 & row_number() == n - 2, 
                        NA_character_, temp)) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  fill(temp, .direction = "up") |> 
  arrange(temp, desc(problem)) |> 
  select(-temp, -n)
#> # A tibble: 8 × 2
#>   name  problem
#>   <chr>   <dbl>
#> 1 blank       0
#> 2 A           0
#> 3 B           0
#> 4 C           0
#> 5 D           1
#> 6 blank       0
#> 7 E           1
#> 8 blank       0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi thanks! the approach does give me some ideas. The "blanks" unfortunately, though, are important to preserve. In my case they represent an unassigned time-slot, so we can't really lose a row or information.

Comment: Remove the distinct() to keep the extra blank.

Comment: Yes, I see that, but the top "blank" can't actually move. The only "blanks" that can move are the ones used to solve the problem rows, as shown in the desired solution above.

Comment: This is clever stuff, Carl. I think I'll be able to run with it. I'm currently looking into how  well it generalizes to larger scale data (in terms of hard coding the n > 2)

Comment: Shoot, yeah, as soon as I add an extra "blank" in the top row the approach breaks down. I've learned a bit from your approach, though, I'm going to play with it a bit more and see if I can figure something out.

Answer (score 0):

Carl, I've built off your approach to create something I think is more generalizable. It's not super elegant, but I do think it works. If anyone else wants to have a go, that would be fantastic.

```
# add more data to top and bottom to ensure only "problems" are being addressed
df <- data.frame(
  name = c("blank", "blank", "A", "B", "blank", "C", 
           "D", "blank", "E", "blank", "F", "blank"),
  problem = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)
)

# find position of the first non-problem name
no_prob_name <- df %>% 
  filter(name != "blank") %>% 
  slice_head(n = 1) %>%
  pull(name)

row_np_name <- which(df$name == no_prob_name)

# rearrange
df |> 
  mutate(temp = if_else(problem == 1, name, NA_character_)) |> 
  fill(temp, .direction = "up") |>
  mutate(temp = ifelse(is.na(temp) & name != "blank", name, temp)) %>% 
  fill(temp, .direction = "up") %>% 
  fill(temp, .direction = "down") %>% 
  mutate(temp = if_else(name == "blank" | problem == 1, temp, name)
         ,temp = as.character(str_glue("{temp}{problem}"))
         ) |> 
  add_count(temp) |> 
  mutate(temp = if_else(n > 1 & row_number() < row_np_name, 
                        NA_character_, temp)) |> 
  fill(temp, .direction = "up") |> 
  mutate(temp = str_sub(temp, 1, 1)) %>% 
  arrange(temp, desc(problem)) |> 
  select(-temp, -n)
```